# Preview mode redirects to Desktop

Tags: habitat

I have few local Sitecore installations, on both of the installations, the Publish/Preview mode redirects the site to Sitecore Desktop. The third installation redirects as expected to a Preview page.

I did republish the entire site. I select the "Content/Habitat/Home" for the Habitat version and "Content/Home" for the second instance. Then I click Publish/Preview button. A new tab opens and it redirects to Sitecore Desktop.

Am I missing something here?

**Redirect Preview does not work for these instances:**

1. https://github.com/Sitecore/Habitat
2. A "Sitecore.NET 9.3.0 (rev. 003498)" installation

**Works for this instance:**

1. https://github.com/Sitecore/Sitecore.HabitatHome.Platform

Answer (score 0):

The Same issue we were facing and issue was with identityserver setup.

Please check Sitecore.IdentityServer.Host.xml config file in indentity site.

check 2 properties:-
1. under "AllowedCorsOrigins"
2. under PasswordClient is same as in main site

also below config file in main site.
Sitecore.Owin.Authentication.IdentityServer.config